# Molar mass on phase transition

Tags: mass, phase-transition, physical-chemistry, molecules

I want to know for a single substance in transition between liquid and gas, if the molar mass will change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to know for a single substance in transition between liquid and
> gas, if the molar mass will change.

No, not at all. Molar mass (MM) is simply the mass of $1$ mole of the substance. During a phase transition no matter is neither created nor destroyed, so the MM doesn't change.

As an aside, the MM of a *mixture of substances* doesn't change either during phase transitions, for the same reason.

Comment: Thanks :). So, the phase change is more than molecular interaction (bond) due to the energy system and therefore it doesnt change molar properties.

Comment: For many substances this is not true. Often the gas phase will be a mix of atoms/molecules from the liquid. For example, the gas above liquid NaCl is not just NaCl molecules...

Comment: @JonCuster For $\text{NaCl}$ the  MM is invariant to the phase, at least if the system is considered ($\text{l,g})$.

Comment: @Abdoulayendiongue Phase changes don't create or annihilate mass. They're invariant to MM.

Comment: @JonCuster The vaour phase of $\text{NaCl}$ still has the ratio of $\frac{[Na]}{[Cl}$, its MM is the same as in solid $\text{NaCl}$.

Comment: Got it now ! Thanks